# Is there a shortcut to go to the YouTube search bar?

Tags: youtube

Suppose I am watching a video on YouTube and want to watch another video. Is there a way to go to the search bar directly with a keyboard shortcut? I don't want to grab my mouse, focus on the small bar and go back to the keyboard again.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's the forward-slash key (<kbd>/</kbd>).

This also works for searching in Google Maps.

Source for this and other YouTube keyboard shortcuts:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7631406?hl=en

Comment: On a German keyboard, it's the hash key (`#`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are within the focus of Flash, all your keyboard shortcuts do not work. All of these are limited to Flash, so tab will switch between different features of the player. (See [this Superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/409116/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-exit-out-of-the-scope-of-a-flash-application-on).)

If you do <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> again to regain focus of the browser, your keyboard controls are back; maybe a single tab or couple of tabs after that will take you to YouTube search.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your browser.

For Firefox, while a video is playing, press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to get the cursor in the search bar.

For IE9, while a video is playing, you need to press the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key 5 times to go inside the search bar.

Comment: I am using firefox, but this trick doesn't work all the time. It works if you just clicked a link and are watching a video directly. But when you have paused and played the video or did some other actions in the flash menu, the `TAB` button will continue from there.

Comment: Oh I see but there is no native YouTube shortcut to go inside the search bar. This is the only solution that I can think of.

Comment: Well that's a pity. I was hoping for some special secret nobody knew of.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not a specific shortcut but this is the only way I can think of instead:

For Firefox: press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>x3 while you are on YouTube.

For Chrome: press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>x1 while you are on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

Forward-slash (<kbd>/</kbd>) doesn't work for me unfortunately. But there are extensions like [Search Box Focus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-box-focus/amgmdnojamodmpfjaokfgpijhpcednjm) that actually work on any website, including  Youtube. Though, you have to use Chrome or a browser that allows you to install chrome extensions such as Opera.

Answer (score -4):

For Chrome, press the TAB button 3 x.

Comment: This simply doesn't work - if it works at all it will be dependent on which element currently has focus.